# ray.init() throws List Index Out of Range error

Tags: ray

I am using version `0.8.6`. The error occurs in the `connect` function in `worker.py` when `ray.init()` was run. I was able to trace the error and it occurs in the below part.

```
if mode == SCRIPT_MODE:
        # Add the directory containing the script that is running to the Python
        # paths of the workers. Also add the current directory. Note that this
        # assumes that the directory structures on the machines in the clusters
        # are the same.
        script_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
        current_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
        worker.run_function_on_all_workers(
            lambda worker_info: sys.path.insert(1, script_directory))
        worker.run_function_on_all_workers(
            lambda worker_info: sys.path.insert(1, current_directory))
        # TODO(rkn): Here we first export functions to run, then remote
        # functions. The order matters. For example, one of the functions to
        # run may set the Python path, which is needed to import a module used
        # to define a remote function. We may want to change the order to
        # simply be the order in which the exports were defined on the driver.
        # In addition, we will need to retain the ability to decide what the
        # first few exports are (mostly to set the Python path). Additionally,
        # note that the first exports to be defined on the driver will be the
        # ones defined in separate modules that are imported by the driver.
        # Export cached functions_to_run.
        for function in worker.cached_functions_to_run:
            worker.run_function_on_all_workers(function)
    worker.cached_functions_to_run = None
```

Line `script_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` assumes that `sys.argv` has to be non-empty, but in my case it is empty.
I disabled copying the `script_directory` to workers and it seemed to be working just fine. What should be the correct way to proceed?

Comment: How are you running `ray`? `sys.argv[0]` is usually the currently running program by convention.

Comment: We are embedding the Python code into C++ code. That may be the reason.

Comment: Can you file an issue with details about how you're starting the python script? https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/new/choose This sounds like a bug

Comment: I had already created the following issue: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/10565.